# Windows authentication denied asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, windows-authentication

I have tried to search stack overflow for some time for an answer to my question but without success.

I have an asp.net mvc3 application with windows authentication.

Because of logging we have to know who is using the application when they access it, and therefore the users are being prompted with a typical login dialog when they enter the page so we can see who is using the application.

When the user enters his/her NT logging details the system then accept their credentials and lets them use the page.
We are getting the different information about users from an Active Directory.

The page is on an intranet and is being accessed from a computer which is logged on a domain which the webpage denies, that is how we get the prompting when the user first enters the page, and the user then enters his/her NT details as mentioned earlier.

My problem is that the system **sometimes keeps denying the users** when they try to login from the computers.

I have checked all of the different things such as anonymous identification and so forth and their shouldn't be any problems with that at all.

I need a place where I can see perhaps some events or some other log about why they are being denied.

This is how the checking of roles has been made:

```
 public class FinancialReportController : BaseEmployeeController
{
```

.

```
[AuthorizeAllExceptShop]
public class BaseEmployeeController : Controller
{
}
```

.

```
 public class AuthorizeAllExceptShop : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !httpContext.User.IsInRole(Constants.Roles.SHOP);
    }
}
```

.

```
public static class Constants
{

    public static class Roles
    {
        public const string SHOP = @"INTERNAL\XP_ShopUsers_DK";
    }
```

**My web config has this line:**

```
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you login success audits. In a domain you can log success and failure audits. So if maybe the AD or local event logs are login success attempts you can also log failure atempts.

Never done a web app like this so not sure if any help.  Just a shot in the dark.

:}

Comment: Hmm at the moment the webserver is the only place where logins are being logged.

Comment: If you are succsfully login, success logins attempts on the web servers event logs, in theory your should be able to log failure logs. :}

Comment: Hmm I have tried to look and all the failed attempts to log in aren't logged anywhere.

Comment: Did u sort this.   have you checked that failure loging is on (off by default) and also, in thery you should see a fail attempt on normal NT login.  try a bad login in as admin and see if u can get that to show in logs.  Just a thought.  see audit policy   logon   and in there u can set success and failure.